# How To get value form 2 table with same condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, t_silm and t_revenue, and I want to sum some both tables with the same condition. This is sample my table:

https://ibb.co/JtCp80w

```
t_silm

bl - th - tw - total
10 - 2018 - 4 - 100
11 - 2018 - 4 - 200
12 - 2018 - 4 - 300


t_revenue

bl - th - tw - jumlah
10 - 2018 - 4 - 25
11 - 2018 - 4 - 70
12 - 2018 - 4 - 45
```

I want to get the result:

```
avg = total / jumlah;

condition =  tw =4 and th = 2018;
```

Please can somebody help me?

```html
$query = "SELECT sum(t_slim.pemakaian_309) as to1, sum(t_revenue.jumlah) as to2, to1/to2 as taverage 
            from t_slim t1 INNER JOIN t_revenue t2 on t1.tahun=t2.tahun 
            and t1.triwulan=t2.triwulan WHERE t1.tahun=$tahun and t1.triwulan=$triwulan GROUP BY bulan";
  
  $hasil = mysql_query($query);
  $baris = 3;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
  $worksheet2->write_string(11, $baris, number_format($data['taverage'],2),$format2);
  $baris++;  
  }
```

Comment: Can we have expected output.

Comment: Can you post the query what you have tried?

Comment: $query = "SELECT sum(t_slim.pemakaian_309) as to1, sum(t_revenue.jumlah) as to2, to1/to2 as taverage 
            from t_slim t1 INNER JOIN t_revenue t2 on t1.tahun=t2.tahun 
            and t1.triwulan=t2.triwulan WHERE t1.tahun=$tahun and t1.triwulan=$triwulan GROUP BY bulan";
  
  $hasil = mysql_query($query);
  $baris = 3;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
  $worksheet2->write_string(11, $baris, number_format($data['taverage'],2),$format2);
  $baris++;  
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about what you want.

First you want to sum the column 'total' :

```
SELECT SUM(total) as total1, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw
```

Then you want to sum the column  jumlah :

```
SELECT SUM(jumlah) as total2, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw
```

Group this 2 query in 1 query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT SUM(total) as total1, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw ) as T1
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT SUM(jumlah) as total2, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw) as T2
      on T2.tw =T1.tw AND T2.th=T1.th
```

Now add the condition and the avg :

```
SELECT T1.th, T1.tw, total1/total2 as avg
FROM
(SELECT SUM(total) as total1, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw ) as T1
    INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT SUM(jumlah) as total2, th, tw FROM t_silm GROUP BY th,tw) as T2
          on T2.tw =T1.tw AND T2.th=T1.th 
WHERE T1.tw =4 and T1.th = 2018;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT t1.total as total1, t2.total as total2, total1/total2 as total_avg 
from t_slim t1 INNER JOIN t_revenue t2 on t1.th=t2.th 
and t2.tw=t1.tw WHERE t1.th=2018 and t1.tw=4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
SELECT sum(t_slim.total) as to1, sum(t_revenue.jumlah) as to2, to1/to2 as taverage 
from t_slim t1 INNER JOIN t_revenue t2 on t1.th=t2.th 
and t1.tw=t2.tw WHERE t1.th=2018 and t1.tw=4
```

this gives you the average as the answer

Comment: still no woriking :(

Comment: $query = "SELECT sum(t_slim.pemakaian_309) as to1, sum(t_revenue.jumlah) as to2, to1/to2 as taverage 
            from t_slim t1 INNER JOIN t_revenue t2 on t1.tahun=t2.tahun 
            and t1.triwulan=t2.triwulan WHERE t1.tahun=$tahun and t1.triwulan=$triwulan GROUP BY bulan";
  
  $hasil = mysql_query($query);
  $baris = 3;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
  $worksheet2->write_string(11, $baris, number_format($data['taverage'],2),$format2);
  $baris++;  
  }